# Реализация функции удаления элемента из бинарного дерева

Tags: алгоритм, структуры-данных, дерево, бинарное-дерево

### Задача вот: реализовать удаление элемента с заданным значением ключевого признака, если он расположен в дереве на заданном уровне.

Написал функцию, которая возвращает ссылку на узел, который нужно удалить. Но как правильно переставить элементы, чтобы не потерять упорядоченность? Плохим ли будет вариантом, если я перепишу дерево поэлементно, исключая удаляемый элемент? Разобрал пару чужих алгоритмов с форумов, в одном получилось так, что при удалении упорядоченность теряется, в другом - много "if-else" (сложные вложенные конструкции по 4-6). Короче говоря, хотел бы получить в ответ алгоритм удаления узла дерева, желательно через копирование в другую память, рекомендации, наставления. Насмотрелся на те алгоритмы, что есть форумах, может, конечно, хорошие пропустил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалить элемент из дерева поиска трудно если это не лист. Вместо удаления ищут следующий (один раз направо, потом налево до конца) или предыдущий (один раз налево, потом направо до конца) элемент. Если это лист, то его срезают с дерева, а значение записывают в "удаляемый" элемент. Если - не лист, то его удаляют рекурсивно, а значение опять-таки записывают в "удаляемый" элемент.

Comment: А если просто обнулить линк к удаляемому узлу а потом вставить в дерево левое и правое поддеревья из этого узла, то разве упорядоченность нарушится?

Comment: Нет, не нарушится. Причина в скорости. Если вы удалите корень дерева, то перестроите его целиком. А можно обойтись числом операций пропорциональным высоте дерева. Обычно это логарифм его объёма.

Comment: Вы не поняли. Я не предлагаю изымать все узлы и по одному вставлять их. В предлагаемом алгоритме, если я удалю корень, то потребуется изменить указатель на все дерево, чтобы он указывал на бывшее левое поддерево, затем  проход по правым линкам бывшего левого поддерева (O log N), куда и прикрепляем бывшее правое

Comment: Высота дерева вырастет в два раза. А по скорости нормально.

Comment: Да, балансировка дерева (если оно было из-за случайности первоначального построения более-менее сбалалнсировано) при таком алгоритме будет ухудшаться. Но ведь в условиях ТС ничего о сбалансированности и не говорилось. Важно, чтобы дерево оставалось деревом поиска.

Comment: Вы правы, так можно удалить узел за логарифм.